need to compactly write the entire Jacobian matrix (derivative) of $\mathbf{X} \mathbf{A}$ with respect to matrix $\mathbf{X}$
I have the matrix product $\mathbf{X} \mathbf{A}$, and I want to find the derivative of this with respect to matrix $\mathbf{X}$, in Jacobian form. We can denote dimensions of these matrices by $\mathbf{X}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{I \times N}$, $\mathbf{A}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times J}$, and $\mathbf{X} \mathbf{A}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{I \times J}$.
Then the Jacobian would be in the form
$\mathbf{J}$ $=$ $\frac{\partial \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{IJ \times IN}$
Given by equation (74) in the matrix cookbook, I know how to express each individual element in the Jacobian:
$\frac{\partial (\mathbf{X} \mathbf{A})_{ij}}{\partial (\mathbf{X})_{mn}}$ $=$ $\delta_{im} (\mathbf{A})_{nj}$ $=$ $(\mathbf{J}^{mn} \mathbf{A})_{ij}$,
where $\mathbf{J}^{mn}$ is the single entry matrix ($= 1$ at $ij$, $= 0$ elsewhere), and thus $\mathbf{J}^{mn} \mathbf{A}$ is a matrix of zeros except for the $mth$ row, which is equal to the $n$th row of $\mathbf{A}$.
Is there a compact way to write $\mathbf{J}$ in terms of this elementwise Jacobian? I am wondering if products like the Kronecker product may be able to write the Jacobian in a simple equation.
Judging by the top answer of this post, my understanding is that the Jacobian would be $\frac{\partial ( \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A} ) }{\partial \mathbf{X} }$ $=$ $\mathbf{A}^\top \bigotimes \mathbf{I}_{I}$, from how the Kronecker product relates to the vectorization. But, it may instead be $\frac{\partial ( \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A} ) }{\partial \mathbf{X} }$ $=$ $\mathbf{I}_{I} \bigotimes \mathbf{A}^\top$. Which one is right?

Since the map $X \to XA$ is linear, the derivative is just $H \mapsto HX$.

Instead of a Kronecker product, use a Kronecker delta symbol to write $$\large\frac{\partial(XA){ij}}{\partial X{mn}} ;=; \delta_{im},A_{nj}$$

The map above should be $H \mapsto HA$, of course.

I'm looking for the entire IN by JN Jacobian matrix. Judging by the top answer of this post, my understanding is that the Jacobian would be $\frac{\partial ( \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A} ) }{\partial \mathbf{X} }$ $=$ $\mathbf{A}^\top \bigotimes \mathbf{I}{I}$, from how the Kronecker product relates to the vectorization. But, it may instead be $\frac{\partial ( \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A} ) }{\partial \mathbf{X} }$ $=$ $\mathbf{I}{I} \bigotimes \mathbf{A}^\top$. Which one is right?

The derivative is naturally a rank 4 tensor (as in greg's comment); if you choose to collapse it to a matrix using a Kronecker product, then it depends on which order you take for the tensor factors, but the result is the same up to a permutation of the rows and columns. Equivalently, it depends on how you interpret the matrix $X$ as a vector, as row-major or column-major.

thank you arkeet, it makes sense that it depends on whether the vectorization is row-major or column-major. I assume that I want column-major, as I think that this particular Jacobian I am interested in, as derived by greg, is column-major,, and I want to be consistent with it. So perhaps $\mathbf{A}^\top \bigotimes \mathbf{I}{I}$ is the form I’m looking for (if that is indeed column-major), rather than $\mathbf{I}{I} \bigotimes \mathbf{A}^\top$.

it also appears from the wikipedia article on vectorization that column-major may be the more conventional way of vectorization, and that appears to be what greg used in greg's derived Jacobian I linked in the previous comment.
